# PySpark: fillna but for string/regex match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can I do something like `fillna` except instead of matching NA columns, can I do something like string contains or a regex match?

For example, my location column have values like `United States`, `US`, sometimes `New York, USA` for example. I want to match things like that into just 1 value say `United States`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define mapping

```py
lookup = [
    ("United States|US|USA", "United States"),
    ("UK|United Kingdom", "United Kingdom")
]
```

And use`when`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   ["United States", "US", "New York, USA", "UK", "London, United Kingdom"],
   "string"
)

country = reduce(
    lambda acc, r: F.when(F.col("value").rlike(r[0]), F.lit(r[1])).otherwise(acc),
    lookup, 
    F.lit("unknown"))


df.withColumn("country", country).show()
# +--------------------+--------------+
# |               value|       country|
# +--------------------+--------------+
# |       United States| United States|
# |                  US| United States|
# |       New York, USA| United States|
# |                  UK|United Kingdom|
# |London, United Ki...|United Kingdom|
# +--------------------+--------------+
```

or `join`

```py
df.crossJoin(F.broadcast(
    spark.createDataFrame(lookup, ("pattern", "country"))
)).where(F.expr("value rlike pattern")).drop("pattern").show()
# +--------------------+--------------+
# |               value|       country|
# +--------------------+--------------+
# |       United States| United States|
# |                  US| United States|
# |       New York, USA| United States|
# |                  UK|United Kingdom|
# |London, United Ki...|United Kingdom|
# +--------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Great stuff! Thank You!